is $ P= \{x \in \mathbb{E} , f(x)=abs(\lVert x \rVert \ -|x| ) =0 \} $ a vector space?
let $\mathbb{E}$ a vector space associated with two norms $\lVert .\rVert$  and $|.|$
let $ P= \{x \in \mathbb{E}  ,   f(x)=abs(\lVert x \rVert \ -|x| ) =0  \}  $
i have proven that $0_\mathbb{E} \in P$
$f$ is not linear .
my question is  $P$ a vector space.
please help me with this question by some hints

Your question is very mixed up: it looks like you are defining $f$ by $f(x) = \mathrm{abs}(|x| - |x|)$, but you have tucked that definition up inside a set builder. Please clarify. It is certainly is not the case that the set of points where two different norms on the same vector space agree is a subspacel.

Take for example $\mathbb{E} = \mathbb{R}^2$, with the standard euclidian norm $|\cdot|$, and the taxi-cab norm $||\cdot||$.
Clearly both $u = (1,0), v=(0,1)$ are in the set $P$, but their sum $u+v=(1,1)$ is not, as $|(1,1)| = \sqrt{2}$, but $||(1,1)|| = 2$.
